# Using .Find to look in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have aset of account names in one workbook (the active one), and I need to use the .Find function to look for their ocurrences in another workbook/sheet. I don't think I'm getting the right Object handle for the other workbook/sheet, but nothing I try is working.

```
For Count = 1 to 10

accName = Cells(Count, 1).Value

AccRow(Count) = OBJECTHANDLE.Find(accName).Row

Next Count
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer with perserverence (it's so rare at the end of the day). Needs to have the Object defined up to .Range, so:

`Workbooks("WORKBOOK").Sheets("SHEET").Range("RANGE")`

I hate VBA.